# Pypi Registration and Updating

Tags: python, distutils, pypi

I have a package that I have registered on Pypi.  Recently I made an update and want to increment the version from 0.6.1 -> 0.7.0.  Now, if I run `python setup.py sdist upload` I get an error: `Upload failed (401): Incorrect password`.

I thought I might have to register it again but get a similar failure:

```
python setup.py register
...
Server response (401): basic auth failed
```

It doesn't ask me the normal question when trying to register:

```
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
1. use your existing login,
2. register as a new user,
3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
4. quit
```

I've had no luck with the documentation or any other help online.  I expect I don't need to register the package again but I can't figure out how to provide a password so the `sdist upload` works.

I've read through the following with no success:

http://guide.python-distribute.org/contributing.html

http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html

https://hynek.me/articles/sharing-your-labor-of-love-pypi-quick-and-dirty/

This was very helpful but still didn't get me to a solution:

http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at ~/.pypirc. If your credentials changed, update them or just delete the file. You'll be asked for your credentials again when you run `python setup.py register`.

Comment: Yes, I had 2 .pypirc files.  D'oh!

Comment: Curious how you could have 2 ~/.pypirc files? Did they have different names?

Comment: One was in the ~/ directory and the other was in the package directory.  Of course I was editing the package level file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have a single .pypirc and its username and password are correct.

Comment: Did you complete the registration by click the link in your email?